# Updating HTML table with instance variables of C# class (jQuery, AJAX)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, ajax

**View**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#getRates").click(function () {
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetDetail", "ControllerName")',
                data: {}
            }).success(function () {
                alert("hit!")
                $('#MyTable').load(location.href + " #MyTable")
            });
    });
});
</script>

 <button type="button" id="getRates" class="button getRates">Get Rates</button>
    <br /><br /><br />
    <table id="MyTable">
        <tr>
            <th width="15%">Name</th>
            <th width="15%">Address</th>
            <th width="15%">City</th>
            <th width="15%">State</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@GetRateModel.OriginName</td>
            <td>@GetRateModel.OriginAddress</td>
            <td>@GetRateModel.OriginCity</td>
            <td>@GetRateModel.OriginState miles</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@GetRateModel.DestName</td>
            <td>@GetRateModel.DestAddress</td>
            <td>@GetRateModel.DestCity</td>
            <td>@GetRateModel.DestState miles</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**Controller Functions**

```
[HttpPost]

    public ActionResult GetDetail(string origin, string destination, string billTo, bool flat, bool rpm)
    {

        GetRateModel total = new GetRateModel
        {
            OriginName = "Name",
            OriginAddress = "Address",
            OriginCity = "City",
            OriginState = "State",
            DestName = "Name",
            DestAddress = "Address",
            DestCity = "City",
            DestState = "State",

        };

        return PartialView("Index", total);
    }
```

**Model**

```
 public class GetRateModel
{

    public string OriginName { get; set; }
    public string OriginAddress { get; set; }
    public string OriginCity { get; set; }
    public string OriginState { get; set; }
    public string DestName { get; set; }
    public string DestAddresss { get; set; }
    public string DestCity { get; set; }
    public string DestState { get; set; }
```

This works when I declare static variables in my model, but I need to set these to an instance of the class instead. How would I wire my table to update based on an instance of my model? I've seen a solution that creates rows with a foreach loop and lists in the model, but I don't think that would be the best solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your view as following:

```
@* try specifying the fully qualified name of your Model class here if the following line gives error *@ 
@model GetRateModel
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#getRates").click(function () {
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetDetail", "ControllerName")',
                data: { origin: "", destination: "", billTo: "", flat: true, rpm: true }
            }).success(function () {
                alert("hit!")
                //$('#MyTable').load(location.href + " #MyTable")
                $('#MyTable').html(response);
            });
    });
});
</script>

<button type="button" id="getRates" class="button getRates">Get Rates</button>
<br /><br /><br />
<div  id="MyTable">
@if (Model != null)
{
  <table>
    <tr>
        <th width="15%">Name</th>
        <th width="15%">Address</th>
        <th width="15%">City</th>
        <th width="15%">State</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Model.OriginName</td>
        <td>@Model.OriginAddress</td>
        <td>@Model.OriginCity</td>
        <td>@Model.OriginState miles</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>@Model.DestName</td>
        <td>@Model.DestAddress</td>
        <td>@Model.DestCity</td>
        <td>@Model.DestState miles</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  }
</div>
```

For more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/views/dynamic-v-strongly-typed-views

Also, I strongly suggest that you use a different View file to render the table data otherwise whenever you click on the button, your final html in browser will contain repeated script tags and repeated buttons.

Comment: Implemented this. Got a "cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference", how would I be able to use an initializing object to mitigate this? (assuming that is in fact the correct course of action)

Comment: in your model you have DestAddresss (with 3 times s), in your view you have DestAddress (with 2 times s)

Comment: It crashes at the first model property, doesn't make it to DestAddress(s).

EDIT: Now getting this error [Object reference not set to an instance of an object] on Model.Name

Comment: please also post the controller code that initially renders the view.

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        } 

This is all I am doing, nothing crazy so I won't update the actual post

Comment: okay, and when does the error occur? on initial page load or when you click on the button ?

Comment: On page loading. Thank for the continued assistance by the way.

Comment: No problem :) I have updated my answer. You can prevent this error in 2 ways: 1) you can wrap your whole <table> element in an if (Model != null) condition. Because you are just returning View() from your Index() action and not passing anything to view, that is why Model object in your view is set to null and causing this error. 2) you can pass an object to View like this public ActionResult Index() { return View(new GetRateModel()); }

Comment: Also, you need to pass some data when making the ajax call on button click, otherwise you will get another error as the bool variables are not optional in your Controller's Action.

Comment: I have faith that this can work! However, response is not defined in your updated answer from what I can see. Is this a request/response ajax query?

Comment: In your ajax request's data property : $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetDetail", "ControllerName")',
                data: { origin: "", destination: "", billTo: "", flat: true, rpm: true }
            }).success(function () {
                alert("hit!")
                //$('#MyTable').load(location.href + " #MyTable")
                $('#MyTable').html(response);
            });

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ no such property according to the official documentation.